# How to fix ValueError: time data '18/02/2020 20:14:31' does not match format '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S' in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

I am developing a web application with Flask Python.
I have a Mysql table with a text column date:

```
-- date --
10/06/2020 18:50:17
10/06/2020 18:55:10
28/05/2020 22:18:06
29/03/2020 20:47:01
29/03/2020 21:29:14
```

These data above are date in string format.
I need to convert these string dates into format dates.

I did this in python :

```
actions = Action.query.all() # This is SQLAlchemy request to get all the rows of table 'Action'
for action in actions:
    date=action.date
    # convert this date string in date format
    date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
    print(date_time_obj)
```

But I get this error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "j:/Dropbox/cff/Python/folder/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
  File "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\_strptime.py", line 577, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\_strptime.py", line 359, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '18/02/2020 20:14:31' does not match format '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'
```

I don't understand as '18/02/2020 20:14:31' corresponding perfectly to format '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'

What is wrong in my code? Did I miss something?

Comment: `%y` is year without century as a zero-padded decimal number. You should use `%Y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You date format should be

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

(with Y in upper case)

Comment: So fast!!! "I can't accept an answer before 12 minutes" said stackoverflow :-) ....

Comment: It was a coincidence. I loaded SO, found your issue that I could answer and I did, that's all :)